# Can’t port forward Sven Co-Op Unturned server but I can port forward a Minecraft server

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding, port

Can’t port forward Sven Co-Op Unturned server but I can port forward a Minecraft server. I cant port forward these games, and I think I know why.

These games are UDP while Minecraft is TCP why cant I port forward UDP?

I did everything correctly, firewall off and on still same, I allowed the ports in firewall still same, is my ISP blocking UDP port forwarding maybe?

When I go check this site while running my both game servers I get this:

[image: Minecraft]

[image: Sven Co-Op Unturned]

[image: cmd]

[image: Static Ip]

[image: Public Ip]

[image: Default gateway page]

[image: Port Forwarding]

Comment: When you forward traffic being received on a port, you typically indicate if UDP or TCP. The more likely situation is you are being a CGNAT.  It likely has nothing to do with UDP or TCP. Likewise, the configuration on your server, has nothing to do with forwarding traffic to the server itself.  While the server must not block the traffic itself, if it never receives the traffic, then allowing traffic on that port will do nothing. You will want to run different services on different ports, it appears, you are trying to run two services, on the same port.

Comment: So what should I do? what d you mean by "you are trying to run two services, on the same port" ?

Comment: `The more likely situation is you are being a CGNAT` how does CGNAT explain minecraft working?

Comment: Compare the public IP your routers gets with what you see in `https://whatsmyip.com/`, and post if they are the same or different. Do you have a static or a dynamic public IP?

Comment: @Albin I think they are the same if by that you mean when I go to my web and type default gateway, login etc, and go to network settings i see IP address: (IP) It is the same in whatsmyip, i made my IP static in windows with a program called port forward network utility, i added 5 more pictures, my default gateway web page, and CMD photo, by the way is it normal for UDP not to have any state at all? that's why I thought maybe UDP is blocked and 27015 not working cause its UDP.

Comment: @Albin if it has anything to do with, im on windows 11, and it used to work before somehow i did manage to make a seven server and strangers joined, but it was before i changed to a new model because the one our ISP gave was disconnecting a lot, now its xiaomi ax3000